# Media query not working as should

Tags: css, size, media-queries, media

I'm trying to make a responsive page for a mobile application and the content is not displaying even though I'm sure I have the right paramenters in my query. I have the background image in a div because I only want it to appear on this page not the entire project. It is working perfectly in the first media query but its not showing up on the second one. Thank you.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-IE">
  <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" >
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  </head>

<body>

<div id="background_img">
</div>
</body>
 </html>

 @media screen and (max-width: 320px) and (max-height: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) 
{            

#background_img {

background-image: url("money.jpg");  
width: 320px;
height: 430px;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
    }

@media only screen  and (max-width: 320px) and (max-height: 568px) and (orientation: portrait)
{

 #background_img {

background-image: url("money.jpg");  
/*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
width: 320px;
height: 568px;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be that the first media query is not closed, there is a missing "**}**" sign.

Try to always keep you code organized with tabs, than you can avoid such these sytax mistakes :)

Comment: Ah thank you very much, thats what i get for using textwrangler rather than notepad ++